# Execute Ubuntu-desktop in remote mode only

Tags: 16.04, server

I have installed ubuntu server 16.04 and the users will work on it through the service XRDP (already installed and configured with the ubuntu-desktop package). The service have been tested and works fine, except with the administrator account but that is other story. The business is, after to have installed the ubuntu-desktop package, when I start the server (local mode) the screen has a graphic interface and not the typical black&white terminal. I would like to know, if is possible install some desktop environment which permits activate it in remote mode only; but keep the classic "terminal" desktop for the admin account in local mode.

Thanks!

Comment: You can switch TTY 1 - 6 by pressing `ctrl+alt+F1` to `F6`.

Comment: Excellent man, you resolved it!

Answer (score 0):

**Booting Ubuntu without GUI**

```
 $ sudo systemctl disable lightdm
```

From there, the computer will always default to starting out with in console mode.

If you have need to use the `Ubuntu-desktop` on that machine, you can start it manually with:

```
$ sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

To return it back to the default of booting to the GUI Login screen reinstable lightdm with:

```
$ sudo system enable lightdm
```

The available TTY's can still be activated VIA <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+(<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>)

Comment: Will this also disable the remote desktop GUI? I thought the original poster wanted to retain the ability to RDP while disabling the local GUI.

Comment: @user68186 No.  That only affects the local machine.  The OP had described using his local machine as a server for remote desktops.  That's one of the characteristics of the way a server operates.  The remote users can use all the resources of the server, including a full GUI desktop from their remote machines.